# Whats the difference between frombuffer and fromiter in numpy?Why and when to use these

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

frombuffer and fromiter both are used for the numpy array creation.But why to these function

Comment: What is your question exactly? Did you read the official doc? Was there anything not clear there?

Comment: `np.array` is the most common array constructor.  `fromiter` can be faster with some inputs.  `frombuffer` requires a specialized input.  The examples use a byte array or bytestring.  If `buffer` or `buffer interface` don't mean much to you, don't put much effort into understanding `frombuffer`.

Answer (score 1):

**frombuffer -:** this is use to **explain** a buffer as a 1-dimensional array.

[Full explain](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html)

eg -:

```
>>> s = b'hello world'
>>> np.frombuffer(s, dtype='S1', count=5, offset=6)
output -: array([b'w', b'o', b'r', b'l', b'd'], dtype='|S1')

>>> np.frombuffer(b'\x01\x02', dtype=np.uint8)
output -: array([1, 2], dtype=uint8)
```

> 

**fromiter -:** This is ues to **create** a new 1-dimensional array from an iterable object

[Full explain](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html)

eg-:

```
>>> iterable = (x*x for x in range(5))
>>> np.fromiter(iterable, float)
output -: array([  0.,   1.,   4.,   9.,  16.])
```